# Regarding help on artoolkit for android and windows

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I downloaded [ARToolkit5](http://www.artoolkit.org/download-artoolkit-sdk) for my windows laptop from the following site.

After installing it, when I run the visual studio solution file from artoolkit folder, it shows error. I had installed video libraries too following the documentation but still it is not working (shows that there is no file in c) and i am not sure how to use the kit in windows.

For using it with android, I downloaded the zip folder of artoolkit for android. I installed eclipse and android studio both. I also setup the android sdk manager and sdk plugin.

But I don't know how to use the artoolkit with android. I cant find any tutorial. Also, is it possible using android studio or will have to use eclipse? I tried to run the applications from bin folder of artoolkit(android) but its not working. I downloaded glut32.dll but problem still persists.I had tried to import the eclipse projects from the unzipped folder of artoolkit fr android. But it is showing some errors.

The platform is 5.1.1 Google API.I am totally new to artoolkit and android development, So it will be really helpful if any initial guideline or resources can be provided.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite all over the place.

ARToolkit does provide you with the source code, but that does not mean that you need to compile it to work with it.

I have no idea of the specifics for Windows, but I assume it is not much different than for Mac.

First question is: What are you trying to achieve?

There are built versions for Unity, Android and iOS which is what most people want. These versions provide marker tracking out of the box, although with different APIs.

Regarding the Android plugin, you can use Android Studio or Eclipse, for Android Studio you need to import the project. I recommend you to look at ARSimple which uses ARBaseLib, which is a wrapper for the NDK methods.

There is documentation, and it is here: http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_developing

Sorry, no idea about your dll problems.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks. I have to develop an android app for the augmentation reality which can be helpful in organ segmentation in medical & surgical purposes. By the way how does ARToolkit generate 3d model and generate markers or trace them. I  am totally new to this , so all of it may sound a bit vague. Even when i am using "andar" project in eclipse, it's showing error. And no information or demo of using artoolkit5 with android studio is available anywhere. Or is it better to use vuforia or other SDK's?

Comment: ARToolkit does not generate 3D models. In fact the Android plugin does only provide you with an OpenGL object. You may need to add integration with a 3D engine. I suggest you use Unity, which can compile to Android, and with Unity you can assign a marker to a 3DObject, the official tutorial is quite easy to follow.